# Double square brackets with variable

Tags: python, arrays

I am rather new to python. I have come across colleagues' code

```
def calc(lst):
    lst = [[some_var]]
```

What does it mean? I guess it's a double-dimensional array, but nothing more is coming to my mind

Thank you in advance

Comment: A nested list (i.e. list within a list)

Comment: You could say a 2-dimensional array, of size 1x1.

Comment: @Chris_Rands thank you, that much i got... But does it mean that I always insert the list as a 'first' list? I dont get to which position it goes in the array

Comment: It's a list. The first (and only) item in that list is a list, whose first (and only) item is `some_var`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @massive_dynamic What? Try doing some simple `print` calls with your example, e.g. `print(lst[0])` should be clear how it works. An array in Python is called a list BTW

Comment: Assuming you mean that you want to add something to the nested list containing `some_var`: `lst[0].insert(0, 'hello')` will give `[['hello', some_var]]`

Answer (score 2):

Variable points to a nested list, where length of outer as well as inner list is 1.

```
In [9]: lst = [[1]]

In [10]: len(lst)
Out[10]: 1

In [11]: len(lst[0])
Out[11]: 1
```

Appending list to an empty list,

```
In [12]: lst = []

In [13]: lst.append([1])

In [14]: lst
Out[14]: [[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data type `some_var` is holding. If `some_var` is a primitive data type, say integer, then `lst` is a list of list of an integer. But if `some_var` is a list itself, then `lst` is a list of list of list